# Need to convert date in d-m-y format to Ymd within query

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I need to compare dates within a query, the date is stored in the database like d-m-y (24-Mar-11) and I need to convert it to Ymd (20110324).

This is what my query looks like, I need to convert the C.SP_COMMENTS_ACTIVITY_DATE to Ymd

Is it possible to do this at run time or do I need a separate function to capture that value then convert it before running this query?

```
return $this->db
->distinct()
->select('*')
->from('SP_COMMENTS C')
->where('C.SP_COMMENTS_USERNAME', $user)
->where('C.SP_COMMENTS_YEAR_CODE', $year_code)
->where('C.SP_COMMENTS_ACTIVITY_DATE >=', date("Ymd", strtotime($this->input->post('user_begin_date'))))
->where('C.SP_COMMENTS_ACTIVITY_DATE <=', date("Ymd", strtotime($this->input->post('user_end_date'))))
->get()
->result_object();
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct...what's the output? any error message?

Comment: No error message, it just does not return anything.  I need to convert C.SP_COMMENTS_ACTIVITY_DATE from d-m-y to Ymd

Comment: Not testet, but couldn't you use something like: 
`$from = date("d-M-y", strtotime($this->input->post('user_begin_date')); 
$to = date("d-M-y", strtotime($this->input->post('user_end_date')); ->where("C.SP_COMMENTS_ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'");`

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('DATE(C.SP_COMMENTS_ACTIVITY_DATE, "%Y%m%d") >=', date("Ymd", strtotime($this->input->post('user_begin_date'))))
```

Comment: they did not work. I tried to_date as well. I am using CodeIgniter's Active Record and it probably does not execute oracle's DATE or TO_DATE function within it.